# HOW TO TRIGGER AZUREDEVOPS PIPELINE FROM GITLAB THROUGH GITLAB WEBHOOK

Tags: azure-devops, triggers, gitlab, webhooks

Unable to trigger azureDevops pipeline through Gitlab webhook

I can poll it using triggers options within the azureDevops pipeline but i am not able to trigger through Gitlab webhook. If anyone have a solution please help me out.

I tried configuring webhook in Gitlab but it couldn't able to trigger azuredevops pipeline

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You will probably gonna need to execute a POST API request to AZDO API

```
POST https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/pipelines/{pipelineId}/runs?api-version=7.1-preview.1
```

[Take a look at this api endpoint](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/pipelines/runs/run-pipeline?view=azure-devops-rest-7.1)

Answer (score 0):

Based on your requirement, here are the steps with which I setup a YAML pipeline to be triggered by GitLab event webhooks.

1. Create an `Incoming WebHook` service connection in the Azure DevOps project settings and take notes of the **WebHook Name** `ADOWebHook` and **Service Connection Name** `ADOWebHookSvcCnn`;
   [image]
2. Generate YAML pipeline referencing the .yml file from the **default** branch of the pipeline; in the `webhook` section, refer to the **WebHook Name** `ADOWebHook` and **Service Connection Name** `ADOWebHookSvcCnn` defined in the `Incoming WebHook` service connection during `step 1`;

   ```
   resources:
     webhooks:
     - webhook: ADOWebHook
       connection: ADOWebHookSvcCnn 
   steps:
   - script: echo ${{ parameters.ADOWebHook.repository.url }}
   ```
3. Generate the WebHook URL; replace the `<ADO Organization Name>`with your Azure DevOps organization name and `<WebHook Name>` with `ADOWebHook` from our example;

   ```
   https://dev.azure.com/<ADO Organization Name>/_apis/public/distributedtask/webhooks/<WebHook Name>?api-version=6.0-preview
   ```
4. Add a new WebHook in GitLab project settings; input the URL generated in `step 3` with the expected event(s) selected;
   [image]
5. Test with GitLab event to trigger pipeline;
   [image]
6. You can check the payload of the incoming GitLab WebHook in the pipeline logs;
   [image]

As far as I have tested, the pipeline only listens and gets triggered by the incoming webhook resource defined in the pipeline-referencing .yml file from the pipeline **default** branch.
[image]

Comment: Thanks for your information...It really helps but Microsoft didn't provide yaml feature for Gitlab In that case how can we define webhook into the pipeline

Comment: Could you also please let me know how can we use YAML file for GitLab Repo as i can see in the azure devops we can only create YAML for Github and repos. I cannot find YAML feature for GitLab repo.

Comment: Hi @Ajay, have you tried with `Other Git` option?